# Stack Overflow T-Shirt: where can I get one for now?

Tags: support, t-shirt

I did my search and found only [this](http://inedomedia.com/store/stackoverflowstore.aspx) link, which is broken

Answer (score 4):

**Newer Edit**: The [shop is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store) again :(

---

<s>**Edit**: This answer was quite out of date. There is a [shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) again that sells [SO shirts](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/t-shirts/products/stack-overflow-t-shirt), among other things</s>

---

There was a store, but it was discontinued pretty fast. They're given out occasionally for miscellaneous things (e.g. the person who [guessed when SO would hit 1m questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/millionth-stack-overflow-question/) got one), but I think that's the only way now, they're not sold anymore

Answer (score 3):

You could make one yourself, lots of online places print t-shirts (not sure which country you're in, otherwise I'd pre-Google some links)

Comment: -1: " __Do not__ use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Overflow Inc." - [trademark guidance page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

Comment: You could always print an anti-stackoverflow T-shirt. Parody is generally well protected in the US

Comment: @mgb - a better parody would be some stackunderwear

Comment: @popular - you really think SO are gonna come after me for printing up the SO logo on a one-off t-shirt for the wife to wear in bed? I can understand if I'm flogging bootlegs but I think it's pretty obvious the OP is looking for something for 'personal use'. Your downvote is a bit extremist.

Comment: @mgb: How about [air quotes around the logo](http://i37.photobucket.com/albums/e77/kpeaton/air_quotes.png)?

Comment: @Kev, I didn't say they'd come after you. But wrong is wrong, whether it's one t-shirt for personal use or ten thousand for what I can only assume is a burgeoning SO merch black market. (And, really, pyjamas for your wife? Are you _that_ addicted to SO?)

Comment: @popular - that was a joke to put my point across (does everyone under 30 take things so literally these days?). Anyway...I think me knocking up a t-shirt for knocking about around the house is fair use because, and I quote from the guidance page: *"because you were not using it "in trade."*

Comment: @popular - pyjamas with "closed - off topic" on them perhaps?

Comment: @Popular - He wouldn't be selling it, would he? Would it be illegal to print out a StackOverflow page? Or should I email SO for special permission to use their logo on a print out? ;)

Comment: @josh, you'll need a lawyer if you actually want to move this from "pithy comment thread" to "serious legal discussion." You mentioned the logo, I pointed out that some logo guidance exists. That's all. Since I am not a lawyer, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Kev I wasn't sure before, but now, [Anna Lear says so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157244/131713).

Comment: stackunderwear....really?