# Where can I buy the Stack Overflow t-shirt?

Tags: discussion, shop, t-shirt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow T-Shirt: where can I get one for now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68841/stack-overflow-t-shirt-where-can-i-get-one-for-now)
>   [What happened to the Stack Exchange Store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store)

Is there a place where can I buy a Stack Overflow t-shirt? I've looked online, to no avail. 
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7):

You no longer can buy T-shirts, the Stack Exchange merchandise shop [closed some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store).

Comment: Is there any plan in the future to reopen it? or any other way around?

Comment: @OliverAmundsen: I know of no plans to reopen it. The SE people sometimes mail SE members free stuff. Who knows, perhaps you'll be such a lucky person one day.

Comment: why did they close?

Comment: Did you read the post my answer links to?

Comment: I am waiting for SE mail :)

Comment: I sent an email to them begging for one.