# Where can I get a Stack overflow T-shirt?

Tags: discussion, swag

Where can I get a Stack Overflow T-shirt?

[I read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157776/where-can-i-buy-the-stack-overflow-t-shirt) before posting my question, but the answers are outdated.

Where can I buy one?

Comment: Why do you think the answer is outdated? It is still correct.

Comment: Sometimes, if you're funny enough and desperate enough, the SE team will just *give* you one. Not that I know anything about that...

Answer (score 4):

Because the shop is closed now, you can't buy one anymore. However, you still can get one. Sometimes, there are contests here on MSO where you can win stuff such as a T-shirt.

Example of a contest: [Work is hard, let's color the walls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213769/229438)

Comment: Yeah, there were three or four such contests in the last winter bash, resulting in about 10 shirts given to winners.