# How Can You Earn StackOverflow T-Shirts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, t-shirt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow T-Shirt: where can I get one for now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68841/stack-overflow-t-shirt-where-can-i-get-one-for-now)

I heard the only way you can get a StackOverflow t-shirt is by earning it now.  So, how can I earn a StackOverflow T-Shirt?  Is there a certain reputation or achievement I has to accomplish to get it?

Comment: I can't find the source, but I do believe you get a shirt for hitting 100,000 reputation on any site (not combined Stack Exchange reputation). You might also be interested in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157244).

Comment: Send exactly 1024 Unicorn dollars to Stack Exchange Inc - One Exchange Plaza, 26th Floor, New York, NY 10006.

Comment: Oh come on . . . im broke man!